# is it possible to connect two external monitors with mini displayport + thunderbolt to displayport or hdmi?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, thunderbolt

I've heard that thunderbolt can be used as a displayport. That make me wonder if I can use two external monitors with mini displayport and thunderbolt to displayport or hdmi.

Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thunderbolt port and display port are the same port.  So it's not two separate ports.

That said, due to the high bandwidth nature of thunderbolt, I suspect we will be able to daisy chain monitors in the future, as well as having thunderbolt "hubs" where multiple devices can be plugged in.

But for now, it's one port.  So only one external monitor.

Comment: // Thank you! I guess I have to keep using USB2DVI.

Comment: Yeah - do you find the quality ok with that?

Comment: // um..I say 95%. One problem with my usb2dvi is that I can notice mouse pointer speed becomes a little bit slower (someone can't notice it) when I move my mouse to the monitor that is hooked up with usb2dvi

Comment: Yeah sounds like lag on the usb port.  Anyway, hope the above answers your question.  Cheers.

Comment: It's now possible to daisy-chain monitors via Thunderbolt.  See image [here](http://www.apple.com/displays/) under "Expand the capabilities of your MacBook Pro".

Comment: Some useful info on this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2763628
Looks like daisy chaining is possible, but no displays supporting it at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbolt can daisy-chain monitors, however the limits of the original system still apply. Mac systems with integrated graphics e.g. Intel HD 3000 can only run one external display. Those with dedicated 3D e.g. 15" Macbook Pro can run a couple of external Thunderbolt displays.