# How would I connect the thunderbolt 3 Macbook pro with a Thunderbolt 2 monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Yesterday Apple launched the new Macbook Pro with USB-C 3.1/Thunderbolt 3 ports, which I ordered already. At home I still have a fairly recent LG 34UC97s thunderbolt 2 display of a whopping €900. I only have to figure out how I'd connect them both?

So my question is: what are the current possibilities to connect a USB-C 3.1/Thunderbolt 3 port to a thunderbolt-2 monitor?

-

I already found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176135/how-to-connect-a-usb-c-based-macbook-to-a-thunderbolt-display), but the bottom-line of that topic is that a year ago there was no solution. One year later, what are the differences?

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like the also newly-launched [Apple Thunderbolt 3 USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=4c). Apple's 12" MacBook has a USB-C port but does not integrate Thunderbolt into it, so Apple did not make a product which needed a Thunderbolt 3 to 2 adapter until now.