# Apple Monitor Thunderbolt adapter

Tags: display

I have a Mac Screen that doest have any ports, instead having only a thunderbolt 1 cable coming out of the back. i have a non-apple pc that doest have a thunderbolt. i do not want to spend $70 on a good adaptor. Help?

Comment: Do you need help finding a serial number? Or manual?

Comment: I do not know what kind of help you want from us? you will still need to purchase something to get the thunderbolt I assume to HDMI or VGA? usually these cables here in uk are like 10pounds. (Thunderbold to HDMI)

Comment: There is no Thunderbolt monitor with “no ports on the back”, can you get the model number (found on the back or bottom) so we can identify the model you’re working with?  Also, please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this is the Apple 27" Thunderbolt Display (the only Apple-branded display *'with Thunderbolt 1 cable coming out of the back'*).

Unfortunately, that display will not work with anything other than a Thunderbolt connection.

[Will Thunderbolt Cinema displays work with Mini DisplayPort equipped macs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20313/will-thunderbolt-cinema-displays-work-with-mini-displayport-equipped-macs)

[Are there adapters to use Thunderbolt Display with non-Thunderbolt computers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17960/are-there-adapters-to-use-thunderbolt-display-with-non-thunderbolt-computers)

Fortunately, these are not made anymore, so you may be able to find a buyer that has more cash than displays and you can have fewer displays and more cash.